# I am getting a nullpointer inside my controllers after giving the fx:id, still the error persists

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have an fxml representation, wherein i have my fx:id defined to be ContentPane

```
<center>
            <Pane fx:id="ContentPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </center>
```

While in the main Application, i have

```
    public class Home_pageController extends Application {

    @FXML
    private Pane ContentPane;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("home_page.fxml"));           
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Some scene");    
        stage.setScene(scene);         
        stage.show();
        MyGrid();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void MyGrid() throws IOException {        
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        Label test = new Label("Test");
        root.add(test,0,0);
        ContentPane.getChildren().clear();
        ContentPane.getChildren().add(root);        
    }
   }
```

I do get the below error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.Home_pageController.MyGrid(Home_pageController.java:70)
    at controllers.Home_pageController.start(Home_pageController.java:62)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Where are you calling `MyGrid()` from? Can you post the rest of the controller code, in particular the place where you declare and annotate `ContentPane`. Please update your code to use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java): it is very difficult to read it if you don't follow the standard naming schemes. Also indicate which line is the one throwing the exception.

Comment: @James_D , do check the updated code pls. Thanks

Comment: The `ContentPane` (sic) will only be initialized in the controller, it won't be initialized in the instance of the `Application` subclass that is created when you call `launch()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `fx:controller` attribute is specified in the fxml, `FXMLLoader` uses the constructor of the class specified as attribute value to construct ***a new instance*** of the controller.

An existing instance of the controller is not automatically reused.

This is why the `ContentPane` field of the application instance that is started is never modified and remains `null`.

Comment: thanks for that, what do you suggest i do?

Comment: @DerinS communicating with the controller to pass the necessary info to it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml BTW: Using the application class as controller should IMHO be avoided.